# How to correctly reserve more space using Stream.Write?

Tags: c#, .net

```
public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{            
   var bytesToWriteTotal = count;

   while (bytesToWriteTotal > 0)
   {
        // If we do not have enough space in the cloud, we'll reserve more
        var capacity = GetCurrentCapacity();
        var delta = Position + bytesToWriteTotal - capacity;

        if (delta > 0)
        {
            Resize(2 * (capacity + delta));
        }
        ...
```

Is it correct way to ensure that I have enough space or I should add `offset` like this:
`var delta = Position + offset + bytesToWriteTotal - capacity;`

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs,a27df287b28d9a2a

Answer (score 2):

Do not add `offset`, it is a position inside the `buffer`, from which you start reading. You read `count` numbers, so that is your number of bytes to write.

You should do the extension once, before the `while` loop:

```
var capacity = GetCurrentCapacity();
var delta = Position + count - capacity;
if (delta > 0) {
    Resize(2 * (capacity + delta));
}
var bytesToWrite = count;
while (bytesToWriteTotal > 0) {
    ...
}
```

Multiplying by two on resize may be too aggressive, because you need only `(capacity + delta)` bytes.

Comment: About multiplying. I think it's a good idea because of complexity. You said that we need to increase the size by delta. If our n operations consist of n writes then we will incur a total cost `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 .. + n = O(n^2)`

Comment: @Anatoly When `Write` is called repeatedly, the caller knows the total, and should call `Resize` before entering the loop calling `Write`. It is not easy to guess the calling pattern form *inside* the `Write` method itself.